# Solving for Roots/Zeros

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$0=\frac{x}{4\sqrt{x^2+16}} - \frac{1}{10}$$

How would i go about solving this?

I have started by bringing the -1/10 to the other side but after that I'm stuck and don't know what to do...

Comment: I would appreciate step-by-step advice/responses so I could understand how to solve this question for the future. After bringing the -1/10 to the other side, would i also bring the sqrt to the other side?

Comment: Square both sides to get rid of the square-root, then cross-multiply (which is safe because x is not zero), then solve the resulting quadratic equation. [Note: one of the solutions is "extraneous".]

Comment: what does extraneous mean?

Comment: It means that a solution of the quadratic equation created by squaring the _original_ equation does not work as a solution in the original equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step solution:

1.Move the $-\frac {1}{10}$ to the other side (as you said). Result: $\frac {1}{10}=\frac {x}{4\sqrt {x^2+16}}$.

2.Cross multiply. Result: $4\sqrt {x^2+16}=10x$.

3.Square both sides. Result: $16(x^2+16)=100x^2$.

4.Rearrange for $x^2$. Result: $x^2=\frac {256}{84}$.

5.Solve for x (two solutions). Result: $x=\frac {8}{\sqrt {21}}$ or $x=-\frac {8}{\sqrt {21}}$.

Finally, we recognize that $x=-\frac {8}{\sqrt {21}}$ is not a solution to the given equation (since the minus sign results in an answer of $-0.2\neq0$), so only take $x=\frac {8}{\sqrt {21}}$ as the answer (you can verify that the latter solution indeed works).

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR THANK YOU! The domain is [0,8] and we're solving for time. So i'm assuming we would just go with the positive solution?

Comment: @Mati So you, apparently, was looking for a complete, very detailed  solution.

Comment: In that case yes you would use the positive solution. In fact, for this particular problem, the negative "solution" does not actually solve the equation. This is because of how the equation was rearranged to solving a quadratic equation, which has two solutions; however, the original equation only has one. And the approximation of the solution is about 1.746 so it is also in the domain you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = 4\tan \theta, \theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, then $\sqrt{x^2+16} = \sqrt{16\tan^2\theta + 16}= \sqrt{16(\tan^2\theta + 1)}= \sqrt{16\sec^2\theta}= 4\sec\theta , \sec \theta > 0$. Thus the equation becomes: $\dfrac{\tan \theta}{4\sec \theta}= \dfrac{1}{10}\implies \sin \theta = \dfrac{2}{5}\implies \cos \theta  = \sqrt{1-\dfrac{4}{25}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{21}}{5}\implies \tan \theta = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{21}}\implies x =4\tan \theta  = \dfrac{8}{\sqrt{21}}.$

Comment: this is the correct answer, i know for a fact but the steps to achieving it are confusing to me? Are you sure we have to use trig functions...

Comment: I simply like to resort to trig when I see $\sqrt{a^2+1}$, and it makes me think of $\sec $...

Comment: oh lol nonetheless did give me the answer i was looking for, never knew trig could be used to get to the same answer. So thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is

$$\frac x{4\sqrt{x^2+16}}=\frac1{10}\implies(10x)^2=(4\sqrt{x^2+16})^2\implies$$

$$100x^2=16(x^2+16)\implies84x^2=256\implies 2\sqrt{21}\,x=\pm16$$

and now end the exercise and get the two **possible** solutions (observe that one of them is *not an actual* solution by sustituting in the original problem)

Comment: It looks like you meant to write $2\sqrt{\color{red}{21}}x = \pm 16$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you very much. Of course, typo edited.

Comment: how would i end up with 8/sqrt21?

Comment: @Mati You'd end in fact with $\;x=\pm\frac8{\sqrt{21}}\;$ , and one of these two values is *obviously* not a solution.

Comment: @Mati Divide both sides of the equation by $2\sqrt{21}$.  One of the roots is extraneous.

Comment: Oh okay makes a lot more sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some simple rearranging it can be seen that your equation turns into
$$\frac{4}{10} \sqrt{x^2+16}=x $$
Now 
squaring both sides, we get
$$4(x^2+16)=25x^2$$
Which simplifies to 
$$64=21x^2$$
So the answer is
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{64}{21}}=\frac{8}{\sqrt{21}}$$